# Hibernate Method Binding

Tags: hibernate

In my UserDao class I have the following method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public int remove(int id) {

    return hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("DELETE FROM User qz WHERE u.id= :id")
            .setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
}
```

Which basically just removes a user from the database based on the Id given as a parameter.

In my User class, I have this simple enum:

```
public enum TypeUser {
    MEMBER, ADMIN;
}
```

What I would like to do is make sure that only a user with a user type ADMIN can delete a user from the database. In other words, I want that method to be visible only to a user of type ADMIN. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't do that in your DAO.
You have to control the user role in your controler..
What you wrote here is the method to delete a user, now what you have to do is, when a user is requesting to delete (if every user has the access on delete action), you have to intercept the request, look its role and then accept or deny the request.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.